# If a state is recurrent (either null or positive) and the MC is irreducible, are all other states recurrent?

Tags: markov-chains

Is this true? I know that if a state is positive recurrent and a MC is irreducible, then all other states are positive recurrent.

To clarify, we are only dealing with finite, countable MC.

Comment: Yes, if $i$ is recurrent and $i$ communicates with $j$ then $j$ is also recurrent.

Comment: and this is true for both null recurrence and positive recurrence?

Comment: Yes, it is true.